# Do a select depending of result of a another select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have simple query like this:

```
    SELECT RoleId FROM Security.UserRoles WHERE UserId = 8
```

It throws me values 1 and 2.

I want to add a conditional if that select contains number 2 do another select like this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(O.OrderId) AS TotalItems FROM Store.[Order] O
```

I try something like this:

if not do an else clause with another select, how can I achieve that? Regards

```
 IF(SELECT RoleId FROM Security.UserRoles WHERE UserId = 8 =2)
```

but my syntax is not correct

Comment: Do you want to generate 2 datasets in stored procedure? Or you want to combine two condition in one query?

Comment: just two conditions, if condition is true do select if not do another select @qxg

Comment: Can you just join two table?

Comment: No, I want two different selects depending of result of first select @qxg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ELSE (IF...ELSE)` in your case like this:

```
IF (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN RoleID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM UserRoles WHERE UserId = 8) > 0 
    SELECT COUNT(O.OrderId) AS TotalItems FROM Store.[Order] O
ELSE 
    Query2;
```

**GENERAL SYNTAX:**

```
IF Boolean_expression   
     { sql_statement | statement_block }   
[ ELSE   
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

**Link to demo:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf55c/3

Comment: why it works with SUM in subquery? Sum functionallity its supposed to sum 1 and 2 no? why it works correctly if found 2 ?

Comment: I have used `CASE...WHEN` in the subquery which checks if it contains 2 then it will assign it a value 1 else 0 Then it sum those 1s and 0s instead of summing 1 and 2. So if the sum is greater than 0 it will tell that it contains 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT RoleId FROM Security.UserRoles WHERE UserId = 8 AND RoleId =2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case statement,close to if

```
SELECT 
( Case When RoleId =2 then
(  SELECT COUNT(O.OrderId) AS TotalItems FROM Store.[Order] O) else 0 end ) count

FROM Security.UserRoles WHERE UserId = 8
```